# How to count multiple occurrences of a string within another string which contains backslash and double backslash?

Tags: powershell, count

I need to count the number of occurrences within a single line from a string that contains backslashes and double backslashes.

I've tried using `.Count`, but it only counts the first instance within the line.  When I try other commands, I usually get some kind of error regarding escape characters.

Here is the one line of data from the file c:\work\test.txt:

```
Occurrence1\\paul\dfs_app\MyFolder\QA2\testme1  Occurrence2\\paul\dfs_app\MyFolder\QA2\testme2
```

And here is my code:

```
$inString = "\\paul\dfs_app\MyFolder\QA2"
$file = "C:\work\test.txt"
$check = Get-Content $file | Where-Object { $_.Contains($inString) }
if ($check.Count -gt 0) {
    Write-Host "Found" $check.Count.ToString().PadLeft(2, " ") "occurrences in " $file -ForegroundColor Yellow
}
```

It returns

> Found  1 occurrences in  C:\work\test.txt

but it should have found 2 occurrences.

Comment: `Count` does not count specific occurrences of your search string. Your `Where-Object` filter returns the lines that contain your search string (regardless of how often it occurs), and `Count` reports the number of those lines. You don't get an extra line just because one line contains your search string more than once.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `Select-String` to count occurrences of `$inString`.

```
$out = Select-String -Path $file -Pattern ([regex]::Escape($inString)) -AllMatches
$out.Matches.Count
```

`-Pattern` without the `-SimpleMatch` switch turns the pattern into a regex. Using the `Escape()` method will automatically escape those backslashes and any other special regex character. Since it is using a regex match rather than a simple match, the `matches` property will contain each match found. Combining that with the `AllMatches` parameter, it will continue match searching after the first match on each line.